# Making a dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Array
{   
    //A dynamic array, use it instead of vector for maximum compatibility
    private:
        T* array;
        size_t used;
        size_t size;
    public:
        //Size is the initial size for the array
        Array(size_t size)
        {
            this->array = new T[size];
            this->used = 0;
            this->size = size;
        }

        void append(T element)
        {
            if (this->size == this->used)
            {
                this->size *= 2;
                T* newArray = new T[this->size];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < this->used; i++)
                {
                    newArray[i] = this->array[i];
                }
                delete[] this->array;
                this->array = newArray;
            }
            this->array[this->used++] = element;
        }

        T operator[](size_t index)
        {
            return this->array[index];
        }
};
```

I wrote this code to make an expandable array, but it gives `<error-type>` error

I am writing it because the library I use is incompatible with all of the `std` libs (vector, iostream, etc)

The problem has to do with `typename`, and i don't really know much about it

The code that I used to test:

```cpp
#include "Headers/array.hpp"

int main()
{
    Array<int> arr = Array(10);
}
```

Comment: Please give example codes  and the error information

Comment: ```c++
#include "Headers/array.hpp"

int main()
{
    Array<int> arr = Array(10);
}
```
cannot deduce class template arguments

Comment: In what way is the library you use incompatible with the standard library?

Comment: I use SDL3 on MacOS, and every time i include SDL and some other std library, i get a linker error

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional information. Don't post it as a comment, code is hardly readable in comments. Thanks. Also share the exact linker error you get.

Comment: Well that's just a build problem.    It will be easier to correct the build problem by editing your build script (e.g.  not using a C driver to link a C++ program, ensuring libraries and other dependencies are linked in an appropriate order) than trying to roll your own version of facilities from the standard library.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vEv86x9Gj <- initialization syntax trouble?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: Why not use build-in containers like e.g. `std::vector`, and then pass pointers to the library, e.g. as per [`std::vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) ?

Comment: `Array<int> arr{10};` works. Note also you need a destructor to delete your allocation or it will leak.

Comment: Unrelated tips: `operator[]` should return a reference (otherwise it won't work the way people expect), `append` should take a const reference to avoid unnecessarily copying T.

Comment: This code has a number of problems: as you use a raw pointer, you need a non trivial destructor, non trivial copy/move constructors and non trivial copy/move assignment operators (rule of five). But it should compile fine and be useable (despite possible memory leaks). Please show the *exact errors*. And using C++ without the standard library is *brave* not to say foolish...

Comment: @gaby *I am writing it because the library I use is incompatible with all of the std libs* -- I bet it isn't.  If the library just requires a pointer to the start of the array, then the `data()` member function of `std::vector` does this.   In other words, the creator of `vector` knew that there were legacy functions that would not take `vector` directly, which is why the `vector::data()` function exists.  You may be spending all of this time coming up with this `Array` class, when `std::vector` does this same work.

Comment: OT: To use a standard naming scheme, you may want to change `used` to `size`, and `size` to `capacity`. Others will then more easily understand your code. Also, using that `this->` everywhere when unnecessary makes the code less readable.

Comment: Voting to close as typo: https://godbolt.org/z/dGjP4vjKh should be `Array<int> arr = Array<int>(10);`

Comment: If you really need to "roll your own" vector class, watch this talk by Arthur O'Dwyer from CppCon 2019: [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). O'Dwyer supplies code and explains how it works.

Comment: If the library is incompatible with `std::vector`, what makes your custom class compatible with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code has some issues.

- `Array(size_t)` should account for a possibility of 0. As written it would lead to dereferencing an illegal pointer on `append()`. Which means that the actual outcome of such a call depends on the creativity of your optimizer (i.e. you really don't want to go there).
- You should write or prohibit the copy constructor and the assignment operator for `Array`. Right now the compiler implements bitwise copy for these which will lead to a possible UB if one copy deletes the memory (in `append()`) and then another tries to access it.
- `operator[](size_t)` should return a reference, not a copy to allow things like `arr[3] = 12`.
- Tied to issue 2, you also should `delete[]` the memory in the destructor (as well as in the assignment operator when appropriate), right now destroying the `Array` object leads to a memory leak (see also "[rule of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)" as well as "rule of zero" for better class design ideas).
- `append(T)` is generally better written as `append(const T&)` although it's more of an optimization note.
- Another optimization note would be to use `newArray[i] = std::move(this->array[i]);` in `append()`.

2. The problem you have with

   ```
   Array<int> arr = Array(10);
   ```

is due to the compiler being unable to tell what `Array` is `Array(10)`. For example, you could write `Array<int> arr = Array<float>(10);`. Yes, it would lead to a compilation error on a later phase but the compiler doesn't guess these things for you. You must write `Array<int> arr = Array<int>(10);` (or, alternatively, `auto arr = Array<int>(10);`).

3. Given the amount of difficulties you're likely to run into when implementing more complex STL classes like `std::map`, I strongly suggest to fix the underlying problem of STL incompatibility instead.

Comment: Thanks! That helped really much, the problem was with the compiler flags.
The command i got in the end: `g++ tests.cpp -std=c++20 -o main -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -lc++
`
(I have an arm macbook)

Comment: I would also add that the code does not at all care about possible exceptions. There are many places where they may be thrown in general, and not treating them leads to leaks, incorrect state, and undefined behavior.

Comment: The main problem remains unaddressed. This code is trying to manually manage memory resource. Thus, it must pay attention to **rule of 0/3/5** for **RAII**. This code is still broken in many ways, due violating rule of 0/3/5. The answer didn't address the huge problem.

Comment: @Red.Wave - I believe I've pointed that out in 1) (which, strictly speaking, isn't what the question was about at all). I also believe I've pointed out issues in a proper order: first one leads to UB, second leads to the code not doing what the user expects it to do; compared to that, memory leak is bad but not logic-breaking.

Comment: You just gave a very short recom about assignment and copy. Not enough stress. UB means incorrect code; a time bomb in the program. Defining template class means intention to reuse. Any sorts of UB in template code is a bug. And RAII bug is one of the fundamental bugs to be prevented. It doesn't just cause resource leak; double-free, and use-after-free are oder problems that arise with improper handling of resources.

Comment: @Red.Wave Fair, moved recommendation about assignment/copy higher. If I were to stress anything, it would be a more general idea "re-implement library classes only as an excercise or when you _really_ know what you're doing"; also, I strongly prefer saying "A causes specific problems X, Y and Z" rather than "A violates a general heuristic F" whenever talking about a specific A.

Comment: RAII is not huristic. There's a reason it is called a rule. Prior to C++11, the language was a bit less complicated and we had the **rule of big 3**. After C++ - due to enhancements - it became 0/3/5. It's a very old and and basic idiom. A large portion of errors in many code bases arise from violation of this single rule. Detailed discussion of it takes to long and better be added as extrar reading reference. But the name and main idea need be pronounced and stressed. The OP will use this library soon, and gets runtime crash and bugs with cryptic messages. Now is time to give him the hint.